# Subgraphs within a graph

Tags: clustering

I am trying to find subgraphs in a graph. The nodes in these subgraphs needs to be more connected with each other than to other nodes.
Example adjacency matrix:

```
MOTIF1: 1 0 1 0 0
MOTIF2: 1 0 1 0 0
MOTIF3: 1 0 1 0 0
MOTIF4: 1 0 1 0 0
MOTIF5: 1 0 1 0 0
MOTIF6: 1 0 1 0 0 
MOTIF7: 0 0 1 0 0 
MOTIF8: 0 0 1 0 0 
MOTIF9: 0 0 0 0 1
```

I need MOTIF 1-8 should be a called as a strongly connected subgraph and MOTIF 9 should be a different subgraph. Any software package that is easier to use or program will be of great help. 
Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried igraph or networkx?

Comment: Working on networkx right now. Running some tests to see if this works. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I tired it and the entire network is shown in the output.

Comment: The connected components feature did give me the entire network as expected. The community/modularity feature gave me sub-networks. Please see my following question. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247175/partitioning-of-a-graph